# How to initialize members of template-base class from derived constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11

This:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    T a;
};

template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T> {
    derived(T v) : a(v) {} // xxx: how?
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Goes boom:

```
test.cc: In constructor ‘derived<T>::derived(T)’:
test.cc:12:20: error: class ‘derived<T>’ does not have any field named ‘a’
     derived(T v) : a(v) {} // xxx: how?
```

If I replace the `a(v)` with `{ this->a = v; }` it's fine, is there any way to initialize members of a templated base class from the initializer list of a derived class?

Comment: You can't, and this has nothing to do with templates. A class can only initialize its own class's members. As far as the base classes go, the only thing it can do is invoke the base class's constructor, and it is the base class's constructor that's responsible for initializing its own members.

Comment: Yes, call a base class constructor that initializes them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah I didn't know that, surprised I haven't run into it before.  I'm doing some weird mix-in stuff at the moment so that's why.  I'll stick with using this->a = v;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the base class in the member initialization list of the derived class.  Since your base doesn't have a constructor you can use curly brace initialization (uniform initialization) like

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    T a;
};

template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T> {
    derived(T v) : base<T>{v} {}
};
```

Comment: You edited out the comment right as I did.  That was pretty quick :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor in the base class and call it in the initialization list of the derived class. ie:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    T a;
    base(T v) : a(v) { }
};

template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T> {
    derived(T v) : base(v) {}
};
```

Comment: That's the consensus, unfortunately my number of constructor arguments depends on a template parameter (dimensionality for a vector class), so I was inheriting to provide proper constructors, I'll just use the this-> syntax

Comment: @SeanMcAllister you can always overload the base constructor for different cases.